# An error occurred while installing bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I tried running bundle and I got this strange error:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ruby/util.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked the `mkmf.log` file, and found the error message.

```
$ cat /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@centralize/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.1.2/ext/mri/mkmf.log

...

Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo

...
```

I just recently updated XCode. So I opened up XCode and sure enough, I had to agree to the terms of use, and allow the installation to run. `bundle` runs perfectly, done!